# terraform solve conflicting provider constraints : no available releases match the given constraints

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, hashicorp

Hello I am trying to plan a terraform update. We are using a complex terraform project consisting of many modules.

I have added a CloudSQL database module which requires `hashicorp/null` version ~> 3.1.0 but it seems like another module from my project has a dependency constraint for `hashicorp/null` version ~> 2.1.

Resulting in the following error :

```
Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/null:
no available releases match the given constraints ~> 2.1, ~> 3.1.0
```

How can I track and update this dependency constraint ? I don't know which part of my project is enforcing it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [terraform providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/providers.html) and [terraform version](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/version.html) commands assist with outputting a dependency hierarchy of your modules and plugins/providers, and their respective versions in the hierarchy. It would be most useful to execute this command from your root module config for the purposes of your debugging.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found that a grep -RiC2 '~> 2.1' would do the job but terraform providers is definitely what I was looking for !